# what event can be used to check the state of an order that has just been paid for on shopware 6.5

Tags: php, shopware6

Hello I have developed a plugin and I am trying to get the state of an order when a customer makes an online payment.

I am currently trying the below

```
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Order\Event\OrderStateMachineStateChangeEvent;

 public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
{


       return [
CheckoutOrderPlacedEvent::class => 'OnOrderReceived',
            OrderEvents::ORDER_TRANSACTION_STATE_WRITTEN_EVENT => 'onMent',
        ];
}
```

I tried to log the data in $event

```
public function onMent(EntityWrittenEvent $event): void
    {
         highlight_string("<?php\n\$data =\n" . var_export($event, true) . ";\n?>");
    }
```

but nothing comes up.

how can I detect the state of an order after payment has been made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [add a subscriber](https://developer.shopware.com/docs/guides/plugins/plugins/plugin-fundamentals/listening-to-events) and listen to `state_machine.order_transaction.state_changed`.

```xml
<service id="SwagBasicExample\Listener\OrderStateChangeEventListener">
    <argument type="service" id="order_transaction.repository"/>
    <tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>
</service>
```

```php
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Order\Aggregate\OrderTransaction\OrderTransactionEntity;
use Shopware\Core\Checkout\Payment\Cart\PaymentHandler\InvoicePayment;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\EntityRepository;
use Shopware\Core\Framework\DataAbstractionLayer\Search\Criteria;
use Shopware\Core\System\StateMachine\Aggregation\StateMachineTransition\StateMachineTransitionActions;
use Shopware\Core\System\StateMachine\Event\StateMachineStateChangeEvent;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;

class OrderStateChangeEventListener implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    public function __construct(
        private readonly EntityRepository $transactionRepository
    ) {
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents(): array
    {
        return [
            'state_machine.order_transaction.state_changed' => 'onOrderTransactionStateChange',
        ];
    }

    public function onOrderTransactionStateChange(StateMachineStateChangeEvent $event): void
    {
        if ($event->getNextState()->getTechnicalName() !== StateMachineTransitionActions::ACTION_PAID) {
            return;
        }

        $orderTransactionId = $event->getTransition()->getEntityId();

        $criteria = new Criteria([$orderTransactionId]);
        $criteria->addAssociation('paymentMethod');

        /** @var OrderTransactionEntity $orderTransaction */
        $orderTransaction = $this->transactionRepository
            ->search($criteria, $event->getContext())
            ->first();

        if ($orderTransaction?->getPaymentMethod()?->getHandlerIdentifier() !== InvoicePayment::class) {
            return;
        }

        // do something if transaction state entered is `paid` and payment method is invoice
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @dneustadt what class im I importing for "StateMachineStateChangeEvent" and "StateMachineTransitionActions" to work at the moment it triggers an "Use of unknown class: "

Comment: I already had this "<tag name="kernel.event_subscriber"/>" registered in my service.xml file

Comment: I updated the answer with the imports.

Comment: yea, seen. if I may ask a another question, is this particular snippet dependent on the order payment status been changed by the payment method? e.g "payment method mapping"

Comment: at the moment my payment method does not change the order payment status from open to paid, and to be honest the snippet above did not work for me yet, but Im thinking its because of my payment method not changing the payment status @dneustadt

Comment: I changed the order payment status on the order page and then did a refresh on the  checked out page, it then triggers it

Comment: Added to the example how to fetch the payment method of the transaction in the listener.

Comment: fantastic, what's the different between order state and transactions state? curious me

Comment: the initial implementation always captured the event state compared to this implementation, you might want to check it